# Should I touch the metal surface of my ESD wristband?

Tags: esd

Most ESD wristbands have a little metal surface (something like 20mm*15mm) and a part of plastic or some sort of cloth that goes around the arm. Is it enough to touch the non-metal part or should I touch the metal part?

In other words: does the non-metal part of a ESD wristband conduct well enough to discharge me?

Comment: The metal part should be in good contact with your arm. There's a large resistor in series with it for safety, if you're worried about that.

Comment: @Hearth I know about the serie resistor of about 1Mohm, my question is about the conductivity of the non-metal part.

Comment: This is difficult to answer as not all ESD wristbands are the same. I would just use a multimeter and **measure it**. As long as there is a reliable electric connection between your body and the ESD wristwrap without the metal plate touching you then there is no need to have it touch your arm.

Comment: To make this work you need to post a specific example we can discuss.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie How? If i try to measure the resistance of my ESD wristband, i get a resistance >200Mohm, but i get that too when i try to measure the resistance of my ESD mat.

Comment: The wristband resistance should be in ohms range. http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/27527.pdf